# Wordpress Login Tracking Google Analytics

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, google-analytics

I have o track this code whit a custom variable in Google Analytics, the code is of wordpress site and check if user is logged in or not.
The specific code is inside this: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L716

The portion of code to track is:

```
function is_user_logged_in() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ( ! $user->exists() )
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

When the condition logged_in is satisfied i have to push to Analytics a custom variable:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
      1,             
     'User Type', 
     'Member',      
      2
   ]);
```

where do I insert the analytics code (this is based on session) to make it shoot only when the condition "logged in" is satisfied?

Comment: How are you inserting the rest of your analytics code?  With a plugin?  In your theme's header?  I only ask as it would be good to be consistent.

Comment: The remaning of the analytics code is added whit wordpress plugin, i think is in "header.php" page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a way to do this in your plugin (depends on the plugin), but assuming the Analytics code is added in the header, you could add the following just before `</head>` in `header.php`:

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
            1,             
            'User Type', 
            'Member',      
            2
        ]);
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

It's untested, but it should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Hobo, so i can insert immediately after the tracking code of analytics like this?

        <script type="text/javascript">
          "google analytics code"
        </script>
    <!-- add tracking code-->
        <?php if (is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
                1,             
                'User Type', 
                'Member',      
                2
            ]);
        </script>
    <?php } ?>

Directly in header.php page?

Comment: You should be able to, yes